# Expected initializer before 'strerror'

Tags: c++, linux, strerror

I am trying to make a function like [this](https://github.com/resiprocate/resiprocate/blob/master/rutil/wince/WceCompat.cxx#L54) which will print out the error details associated with it's error number, but i am getting the error `error: expected initializer before 'strerror'`. Here is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

static char* messages[] = {
    "No error",
    "EPERM (Operation not permitted)",
    "ENOENT (No such file or directory)",
    "ESRCH (No such process)",
};
static const int NUM_MESSAGES = sizeof(messages)/sizeof(messages[0]);

extern "C" char * __cdecl strerror(int errnum)
{
  if (errnum < NUM_MESSAGES)
     return messages[errnum];
  return "Unknown error";
}

int main()
{
   int a;
   for(a=0;a<5;a++)
   {
       std::cout<<a<<" "<<strerror(a)<<"\n";
   }
   return 0;
}
```

How to solve this problem ? Thanks

Comment: `std::strerror` does not resolve the problem @Galik

Comment: You've copied Windows-specific code. Remove `__cdecl`.

Comment: Thanks @molbdnilo , post this as an answer, i'll accept it

Comment: @molbdnilo, also, please elaborate. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized that the answer I gave doesn't address the actual question. The key problem here is that when you `#include <cstring>` you get all the identifiers from the standard C header `<string.h>`, declared in namespace `std`. In addition, you **might** (and probably will) get all those names in the global namespace as well. So when you write your own function named `strerror` you'll get a direct conflict with the C function `strerror`, **even if** you sort out the `__cdecl` stuff correctly. So to write your own error reporting function, give it a name that's different from any name in the C standard library, and don't bother with `extern "C"` and `__cdecl`. Those are specialized tools that you don't need yet.

```
char* error_msg(int erratum) {
    if (errnum < NUM_MESSAGES)
        return messages[errnum];
  return "Unknown error";
}
```

Comment: Yes, i changed the function name and it's working fine :) Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Don't write your own declarations of standard library functions. They will often have compiler- and system-specific details that will require you to write a bunch of conditional code that the writer of the library has already done for you (and done it better). For `strerror`, `#include <string.h>` is all you need. Better, though, is `#include <cstring>`, and use `std::strerror` when you call it.